# Is it possible to perform bit operations on a float in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I have some C code that I am converting to java with a lot of bit level operations.

I have the following code:

```
float test(float uf) {
    return uf ^ (1 << 31);
}
```

In the original C code, `uf` was an unsigned value. Since java doesn't have unsigned values, I changed `uf` to a float. Now, I get an error saying that the the first type is a float and the second is an int.

I know there are libraries for it, but I just want to use bit operations just to see what I can do with Java using bit operations out of curiosity.

So, my first question is, is it possible to perform the operation above using Java without using libraries? Second, are there any reasons that you should not work at a bit level in java (besides the fact that there are libraries to do it for you)?

Comment: you could of course implement your own "bitshift on floats", but [there is no built-in bitshift on non-integral primitives in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). As for your second question: the bitshift on a non-integral type is much harder for humans to interpret than on integral types. Therefore one could make an argument that this operation reduces the understandability of the code.

Comment: You've already broken your code: an arbitrary 32bit value (your typical unsigned value) doesn't fit exactly in a 32bit float which has only 24 bits of mantissa.  There'll be truncation.  So translating unsigned to float doesn't work.  You _might_ be able to try doubles instead ... but I suspect your idea is broken and you should try something else.  If you _are_ working with 32bit ints in C then in Java try a 64-bit long.

Comment: You can emulate uint with int just fine. You *cannot* emulate uint with float.

Comment: If you really wanted to manipulate the bits of a `float` you could use `Float.floatToIntBits(float)`. But it doesn't really sound like that is what you want to do.

Comment: @Sam Yeah, I am trying to do it using only bit operations.

Comment: *"Since java doesn't have unsigned values, I changed uf to a float."* This is where you lost me. These data types have different binary representations and different sets of values. So really, why? Maybe you should show us the original C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No. We cannot bit shift in floats.

That operation simply flips the 31st bit (starting from zeroth). You can do that in java just fine.

```
int test(int uf) {
    return uf ^ (1 << 31);
}
```

That's your function. The problem you have isn't setting that bit, it's knowing that if that number is negative that its actually a number 0xBFFFFFFF larger than that number. So long as you are consistent with treating ints as a sequence of 32 bits rather than checking it's value at in opportune times, you'll do fine.

---

If you want 32 bits that give you a proper number. Use a long.

```
long test(int uf) {
    return (uf & 0x00000000ffffffffL) ^ (1 << 31);
}
```

Then you can use it in comparisons properly, and simply cast it to int if you need it as int. Which if we're converting the unsigned to other types is a far superior answer than floats.

---

Answer 2: We should certainly use bit operations in java as they are really fast in java. Quite often in mission critical code it's best to convert over to them at the critical points, to the point of only using primitives, or even native compiled code.

Comment: The title of the question specifically asks about bit operations on `float`s. This answer therefore misses the first question completely. The second question is not answered.

Comment: FWIW you can easily flip the sign of a float.. not that it's going to help OP in general

Comment: doh, it flips the bit rather than sets it, so I need to pay attention to the potentially negative value of uf and preserve that as an unsigned. Sorry bout the temp wrong answer.

Comment: tl;dr: `return  (-1 * uf);`and let the JIT-compiler do the rest.

Comment: @Turing85 pro tip: that's not the same thing as `uf ^ (1 << 31)` at all

Comment: @harold it is on `float`s ;)

Comment: Well ok, but having a float there doesn't solve OPs problem, only his weird attempt

Comment: @harold What's weird about it? Is the question confusing? I'll try to clarify if so.

Comment: @JustBlossom the question is fine, but it's a classic XY problem and the way you've chosen to solve your problem doesn't work. Even if we solve your immediate problem (ie just negate that float), you would just run into more and more trouble, some of it really hard (exponent trouble), and some ultimately unresolvable (NaN).

Comment: @Turing85 There is more to the question than just the title, and you don't appear to have read it

Answer (score 4):

While you cannot directly apply bit operations to a float, it is possible to convert a float to an integer with the same bit representation (to clarify: the bits will be equal, the number value will not).

- [Float#floatToRawIntBits(float)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float)) to get the bit representation of a float
- [Float#intBitsToFloat(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)) to convert back to a float

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operations are not allowed on non-integer types in java.  See this reference: 
http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-bitwise-operators.php.

As far as any reason to "not work at bit level".  The answer is no.  There are many legitimate reasons to do bit wise operations in Java.  Examples would include JavaCard applications, dealing with low level network protocols, and others.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers said, there are no bitwise operations in floating point values in Java. However, this part of your question clearly states that this is an instance of the XY problem: you are looking for the solution for Y while you actually want to solve X because you thought that Y was the best solution but now you're stuck.

> In the original C code, uf was an unsigned value. Since java doesn't have unsigned values, I changed uf to a float. Now, I get an error saying that the the first type is a float and the second is an int.

Why cannot you use either a long or a normal int? It is true that common Java arithmetic operations consider the int values as signed, but there [methods in java.lang.Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) that operate on two int values considering them as unsigned.

So, where in C you would do this:

```
unsigned int fun(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    unsigned int x;
    scanf("%u", &x);
    return a * x + b/2u;
}
```

In Java you would do this (note that addition and multiplication are the same operations for either signed or unsigned integers when 2-complement representation is used):

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    // You need to get the value as a string first, there is no nextUnsignedInt in Scanner
    int x = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next());
    return a*x + Integer.divideUnsigned(b, 2);
}
```

Comment: Even multiplication is the same for signed and unsigned, which is why multiplyUnsigned is not a thing.